# WCF service shared storage

Tags: .net, wcf

I have simple WCF service with 2 methods: Write, Read. First method will store simple data in some storage, and another method will read this data by key.

Data should be available to read right after write method call. Also data should be stored for short period of time(configurable, like 10 mins TTL).

What it best solution to store these data for different users?

Something like System.Runtime.Caching/memcached/mongodb?

**UPD. Any suggestion? Not ideal but good?**

Comment: it depends. Does the data have to remain even after it is retrieved? Is this in a multi-threaded environment? How big is the data you want to store?

Comment: multi-threaded environment - YES;Does the data have to remain even after it is retrieved - YES; data size is small, couple kb per item;

Comment: Will you be storing hundreds of items or more like millions?  Does the data need to remain even if IIS host is recycled?

Comment: Will you be storing hundreds of items or more like millions? - YES Does the data need to remain even if IIS host is recycled? -YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have following options:

**1. System.Runtime.Caching**

Pros:

- Built-in, cheap to implement
- Has expiration mechanism

Cons:

- Concurrency issues, your key will need to be unique
- Malicious users may retrieve data of other users in case of a simple key
- Data will be lost after wcf service host restart

**2. [WCF Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx)**

Pros:

- Simple access to cached data, same service instance is used to process user requests.
- No concurrency problems, users are isolated by sessions.

Cons:

- Memory overhead, single service instance created for each session
- Constrains workflow with session start/end [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true, IsTerminating=true)]
- Data will be lost after wcf service host restart

**3. [ASP.NET session state](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx)**

Pros:

- Built-in sessions with persistence mechanism (data not lost on restart, see sessionState mode="SQLServer").
- No concurrency problems, users are isolated by sessions.

Cons:

- Works only in compatibility mode, mixes two technologies.
- Requires sql server

**4. Self-implemented storage, ranging from file system to sql server/mongodb**

Pros:

- Data not lost on restart
- May have inner data expiration mechanism, based on jobs.

Cons:

- Cost of deployment/configuration/support
- Manual implementation
- Manual user isolation/concurrency/security handling

Based on answers in your comments, you have:
multi-threaded environment, where data have to remain even after it is retrieved 
(I assume until expiration time runs out), and data size is small, couple kb per item;
You will be storing hundreds of items, and data need to remain even after service restart (again, until expires).

Now it depends - in case of production-grade system which potentially can require fault-tolerance, 
load-balancing and scaling - I would choose sql server, even though it means greater dev costs.

If you need to have quick and dirty solution for testing/demo purposes - go with in-memory caching (of course, in this case you will have to abandon -persist after restart- requirement).

Another quick solution would be to store data in temp files where key is file name. This would persist data between restarts, but would have same problems with security and concurrency.